# Sharing session object accross multiple browsers

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to share session objects like user object accross multiple browser? My requirement is if user tries to switch between different browsers(IE, Chrome or Fireforx), the application should allow the navigation along with sharing of user object.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing session between browsers is not possible, Session cookie is used by browser to identify each client uniquely and it is stored in browser memory. So one browser is not allowed to access the memory of other browser and this makes it impossible to share session between different browsers. Reading more about [**session cookies**](http://www.cookiecontroller.com/session-cookie.html) could make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It **IS** possible. But it would require you to write your own `SessionIDManager` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionidmanager.aspx

If you create your own `SessionIDManager` YOU decide how you will determine if a request belongs to a specific session or not. The client IP should at least be one parameter, some application specific key could be another etc. The actual session key that is returned could be a suitable string representation of a hash of all the parameters (the generated session id **MUST** be unique for each session).

Once you have you `SessionIdManager` done you can hook it up in `web.config`:

```
<sessionState mode="[mode]" ...
    sessionIDManagerType="[full type name of your class here]" ... />
```

So it **can** be done.

But I would personnally not make such a class unless there is some really compelling reason to do it:

- It would be really easy to get it wrong and mix up sessions for
  different users.
- What if different user access you site through the same proxy? What
  if there is a load balancer in front of you site (=all requests seem 
  to come from the same IP). And so on.

And also, maybe most importantly:

- It breaks the users' expectation of how sessions usually works...